# Separating JUnit standard output from test case output

Tags: junit, stdout, stderr

Is there a way to run JUnit programmatically in which I could pass custom PrintStream for all output of JUnit framework itself and leave standard output for test cases?

I see that JUnit internally is using JUnitSystem and TextListener to achieve this but I don't see intended entry point to use it without modifying or extending JUnitCore.

Does anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What output is JUnit giving that is causing you a problem?

Comment: It is actually other way around, code being tested is causing problem to me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that `JUnitCore` and the classes used underneath print anything to standard out. The notable exception is `JUnitCore.main`, but this is just the main method for direct command-line execution. Instead you should use one of the `run` or `runClasses` methods. Your own `RunListener` can then output whatever/however it desires.